# No responde eventos en Chrome cuando la URL esta embebida - Genexus

Tags: java, genexus, chrome

Cordial Saludo,

El tema es el siguiente: Tengo una página, desarrollada en Genexus 16 U9, cuando esta es embebida en un HTML no responden los eventos, y sucede en Chrome y Edge, si esto mismo se prueba en Firefox, si funciona.

Este es un ejemplo del embebido de la URL:

```
<html>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://10.0.12.10:8080/RealMultiCiudadanoJavaEnvironment/servlet/com.realmulticiudadano.wpinicio" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</html>
```

Al revisar en el Navegador aparecen los siguiente errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeciendo de antemano cualquier ayuda.